# How much of territory do buffers cover using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, overlapping-features, calculate-values

Is there a way to obtain how much % of the country covers that buffers using QGIS?

This is a country (Ecuador)

[image]

And these are buffers

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your Ecuador layer is several polygons, I would start off by running the ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) tool. This will create 1 merged feature.

Following that, I would run the ["Multiparts to Singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) tool on the dissolved layer. This is because you have some disconnected polygons. You should now get like 5-10 features (based on your screenshot), but it may vary depending on the number of islands you have.

Lastly I would run the ["Overlap Analysis"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#overlap-analysis) tool on the singleparts layer. For your input layer, pick the *"singleparts"* layer. For your overlap, pick the pink circles *"buffers"*. The output will have two columns, one is the area of overlap, the second column is the percentage overlap (which is your desired output).

Comment: Working well, Thanks